# How to use Elasticbeanstalk without ngnix (just with application load balancer)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I have my server application deployed in AWS with Beanstalk.
I'm using Beanstalk with Application Loadbalancer.
Beanstalk is very handy in autoconfiguring all for me and I like to use it, but,
for now, every Beanstalk instance contains NGNIX for proxy requests, but because I already have LoadBalancer that redirects requests to my server and responsible for SSL certificates, I don't see why I need NGNIX and I want to remove it from configuration (or at least not to use it between LoadBalancer and Application server).
Moreover, during my load testing and hight load, NGNIX causing me troubles (it takes a lot of CPU time, and crying about worker_connections)
But I can't find any option to use my beanstalk with load balancer without NGNIX

Comment: If in your configuration the load balancer redirects all requests directly to the other webserver, how is Nginx involved in it?

You could reconfigure Nginx, so it wouldn't listen any ports that are in use.
Or you can disable auto-starting of Nginx service via container commands.

Alternatively, you can use non-preconfigured platform when you're creating an app on AWS EB, like Docker platform or custom platform where you can install only services you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed my problem by configuring load balancer in my EBS. My application was listening on 5000 port (Java), and NGINX redirects from 80 to 5000, Load Balancer sends all requests to 80.
So I have following configuration by default
LB->80:NGNIX->5000:Java server
I've changed in LB Processes from 80 to 5000 so current configuration looks like following: LB->5000:Java server, so LB will redirect all requests directly to my service.

You can see configuration details in
[documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environments-cfg-alb.html) #processes paragraph